# How we convert TOM

Tags: remote-sensing

TEMIS NO2 tropospheric Data by KMNI Netherland is retrieved in TOMIS (ASCII) format. My issue is to convert the said format in to ESRI Gird format or any other Raster format to analyze the  retrieved data file in ArcGIS format. Thanks

Comment: The native data is in HDF or netCDF format as far as I remember.  What portal are you using to download ASCII data?  You should be able to acquire the HDF data, and ArcGIS will open it like it opens a NetCDF.  https://www.temis.nl/airpollution/no2.php   Though, analysis of HDF data is probably best done using tools for that data format, rather than bothering with ESRI.